# How to return a zero vector in Loki LogQL metric query when grouping is used and result would be No Data?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I have the following Loki query:
I want to use this to create a Grafana alert that alerts when "somelog" appears in the log.

```
sum  by (namespace) (count_over_time({namespace=~"something.+", container="backend"} |= "somelog" [$__range]))
```

It correctly calculates the total count of a specific log in the given range across all namespaces.
[image]
My problem is, when zero log line matches, the result is No data:
[image]
Instead of no data I want vector(0), but I am unable to change the query to work like this.

I tried putting `or vector(0)` somewhere in the query, but it is ot working. I could achieve to get `vector(0)` when everything is No data, but this also results in having a `vector(0)` (blue line) result even when some namespaces have data:

[image]

Comment: You have an additional metric, because `vector(0)` has no labels, and or works based on labels matching. If all you want is to get 0 when nothing returned for any namespace, you can use `or on() vector(0)` instead.

Comment: If you want to see 0 for every namespace, that doesn't produce value at the moment, you'll require some more elaborate query.

Comment: @markalex I tried `or on() vector(0)`. It is still not perfect, because if in the given range for the first half of the range there is data, but for the second there isn't, then vector(0) will activate in that second half and I only want 0 when there is no data at all for the whole range. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think that what you describe here should be solved in query. Consider doing it with panel's option "No value".

Comment: I am actually using this for a Grafana alert, that's why I don't want no data. I'm not sure what you mean, I don't see any "No value" option.

Comment: Then [edit] your question and explain your end goal there, because it's important. You want alert to happen, if something is not present in log over last N hours?

Comment: I've added the goal to the question. I simply want to alert when "somelog" appears in the log. When it is not present in the logs No data is the result and it results in strange behavior, that is why I wanted to never show no data just numbers. 
By strange behavior I mean that two alert instances with No data status are shown, one for the query and one for the other expressions (reduce and threshold).

Comment: I don't understand, why `or on() vector(0)` is not what you want. It would result in is exactly what you described: no data is never shown. Whenever query stops producing values of actual logs, it switches to producing zeros.

Comment: " or on() vector(0) " worked for me. Thanks guys.